# Placement of labels on bent arrows in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I added labels to the arrows in an example of the `tikz-cd` manual:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r, bend left=50, ""{name=U, below, draw=red}]
  \arrow[r, bend right=50, ""{name=D, draw=red}]
  & B
  \arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D]
\end{tikzcd}
```

Which gives this:

[image: diag1]

Now simply setting A and B to lower case results in the following diagram, where the label of the upper arrow is off:

[image]

The reason seems to be that the upper-case letters A and B have the same height, whereas a is smaller than b. Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: You could use `\strut a` and `\strut b`.

Comment: You can create a style `\tikzset{s/.style={rectangle,anchor=center}}` and then use it in the two cells like this `|[s]|a` and  `|[s]|b`.